# How was counted one second in computers

Tags: computer-architecture, clocks

I would like to know how was counted 1 second in computers. I mean how machine can understand period of 1 second. Who and when resolved this problem, and more important how ?

Comment: Why should it worry about human time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the computer has a "clock". This is a chip that generates a pulse every fixed period of time, say, every 1 millisecond, generated usually via a [crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator_frequencies).

With sophisticated techniques of clock multiplying, one can get to higher (internal) clock rates.
(see e.g., [frequency divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_divider) and [CPU multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_multiplier))

Counting second (or any long enough time) is now simple - the computer can count the number of "clock ticks" to estimate the time that has passed. If the external clock signal has a pulse every 1 millisecond, then after $10^6$ such pulses, about 1 second has passes. This is not precise, because the computer takes some time to count each pulse, but such an impreciseness is order of magnitudes smaller than milliseconds.)